# Missing file (apache-vhosts.conf) in EasyPHP Devserver17 Apache 2.4.48

Tags: apache, virtualhost, easyphp, easyphp-devserver

ERROR ON STARTUP
Don't panic, it should be easy to fix.
Read the error message below, fix the error(s) accordingly and restart the server.

> eds-httpserver.exe: Syntax error on line 597 of C:/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-binaries/httpserver/apache2448vc15x64x230804074202/conf/httpd.conf: Could not open configuration file C:/EasyPHP-Devserver-17/eds-dashboard/apache-vhosts.conf: The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by copying the this file `C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-binaries\httpserver\apache2448vc15x64x230804074202\conf\httpd-vhosts.conf` into this directory `C:\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-dashboard` and renamed it to `apache-vhosts.conf`